# AnimateLayoutChanges= true in LinearLayout does't work in ViewPager2

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-animation, android-viewpager2

I have a custom view which has **LinearLayout** as parent. Custom View has 2 child views. One is visible by default and other is visible on click of first visible child. I added tag **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"** in parent linear layout so that when hidden child is being shown it should animate. So i have used this custom view inside item of recycler view in fragment. Whenever i show or hide any child view in my custom view, it animates perfectly. But when i use same fragment, same recycler inside **ViewPager2**. It neither show animation nor show the view. Below is the xml file for the custom view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/deliveryByLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <TextView
        style="@style/text_black_10_regular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layout transition type CHANGING, which is disabled by default. To enable it in code:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.deliveryByLayout);
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = layout.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```